# angular 2 default route is not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-routing

This code I have in my routing.module.ts:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'Home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }    
];
```

My angular2 application can be accessed from another web application. Below is the url on that web application:

http://myserver/virtualDir/

On click of this url my angular2 application is loading but it doesn't redirect to Home page. Instead I see only header. When I press Ctrl+F5 Home page is loading and url is also changing.

On that other web application If I provide URL without slash "/" at the end then on click of link application goes to Home page. I couldn't figure out what is the issue here.

Comment: Is this your only Routing module in the project? Or in other words, is this your `app.routing.ts` file?

Comment: Yes this is only routing module file in my project.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it but why are your routes capitalized? That's bad practice.

Comment: changed everyting in lower case still not working.

Comment: Do you get any error in the debugger's console when you only see the header?

Answer (score 0):

try setting base-href in your index.html file

```
<base href="/virtualDir/">
```

Comment: In my app.module.ts I am using this code providers:[{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/virtual dir/' }]

Comment: virtualDir or virtual dir ?

Comment: it was a typo. I am using virtualDir